# Firebase Cloud Messaging stopped working

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I successfully set up Firebase Cloud Messaging and was able to send myself some push messages in the notifications console using the FCM registration token of my device.

I was playing around with cloud functions to try to send some push notifications using [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications). I wasn't able to make it work so when I went back to try to send myself some push notifications using the console this had also stopped working. I don't believe I made any changes to my code in the meantime.

I followed [this guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html) for debugging and I was able to successfully send and see a push notifications using the curl command

```
> curl --http2 --cert ./myapp-push-cert.pem \
-H "apns-topic: com.example.yourapp.bundleID" \
-d '{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APNs!","sound":"default"}}' \
https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/ab8293ad...c0d
```

and I also tried making a call directly to FCM using curl

```
> curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: key=AU...the rest of your server key...s38txvmxME-W1N4" \
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d '{"notification": {"body": "Hello from curl via FCM!", "sound": "default"},
"priority": "high",
"to": "gJHcrfzW2Y:APA91...the rest of your FCM token...-JgS70Jm"}'
```

and had the following success message:

```
{
 "multicast_id":8128425267989767985,
 "success":1,"failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,"results":[
   {"message_id":"0:141292123136432%e3eee07da3edd08d"}
 ]
}
```

But I am not seeing any notification from this curl. The [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) shows no issues.  I've tried on a second device with the same results. I have tried keeping the app both foreground and background. What could be the issue?

EDIT: Here is the code i'm using to setup and receive notifications:

```
  //called from applicationDidLaunch
  private func setupNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token())
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
    FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


  }

  //this is successfully called
  @objc private func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      firebaseController.setTokenInDatabase()
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    connectToFcm()
  }

  //just like in the blog post ive tried both with and without the connectToFcm() method
  private func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
      return
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
      if error != nil {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Oh no! Failed to register for remote notifications with error \(error)")
  }

  //this is called successfully too
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var readableToken: String = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
      readableToken += String(format: "%02.2hhx", deviceToken[i] as CVarArg)
    }
    print("Received an APNs device token: \(readableToken)")
  }

  //neither of the following methods are no longer called
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }

  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("didReceive", response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("willPresent", notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler([.alert])
  }
```

Comment: Are you not receiving messages on multiple devices or just a specific one?

Comment: I've tried on a second device and I am experiencing the exact same behaviour, the first curl works but not the second

Comment: Could you also post your code snippet for receiving the messages? Are you trying to receive the notification when your app is in foreground or background?

Comment: I've tried both in the foreground and background and both were working previously but neither is working now

Comment: Please see my edited answer for the code to  setup and receive notifications. However since I am receiving notifications directly from APNS I don't think there is anything wrong with the code I am using to receive notifications.

Comment: I believe I'm seeing something similar in a project, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I didn't fully solve it but I noticed that calling the firebase setup method twice reproduced it, so try checking to see if you are doing it twice

Comment: Mine was all set and working last week.  I made  no changes to Firebase cloud messaging after that...this week its not working.  And in the firebase cloud messaging console settings, I see all the senderID, server keys have changed and my iOS app is no longer linked - in fact that section just spins and spins...I can only see partial new server key - I can only delete it...can't even see the whole thing.  Something broke!